# C++: Pointers outputs confusing me

Tags: c++, pointers

So I have the following code:

```
    cout << _userLoginName << endl;
    cout << *_userLoginName << endl;
    cout << (_userLoginName+1) << endl;
    cout << *(_userLoginName+1) << endl;
```

the variable `char * _userLoginName` has been set equal to `"smith"`. My question is simple: Why in the last lines of code do I get the following output?

```
smith // as from cout << _userLoginName << endl;
s // as from cout << *_userLoginName << endl;
mith // cout << (_userLoginName+1) << endl;
m // cout << *(_userLoginName+1) << endl;
```

I really did try reasoning the result but I cannot figure it out.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you give `cout`<sup>1</sup> a `char *`, it will try to print a string.  If you give it a `char`, then it will print that single character.

`_userLoginName` and `(_userLoginName+1)` are of type `char *`; `*_userLoginName` and `*(_userLoginName+1)` are of type `char`.

---

<sub>1. Technically, "give `std::operator<<(std::ostream &, T)`".</sub>

Comment: How can I print is actual value then (the address of the parameter)?

Comment: @Yokhen: To print an address, you can usually get away with something like `cout << static_cast<void *>(_userLoginName)`.

Answer (score 2):

Pull out a sheet of paper and draw a box with six cell with "smith" written into them:

```
+-+-+-+-+-+--+
|s|m|i|t|h|\0|
+-+-+-+-+-+--+
 ^ ^
 | +- _userLoginName + 1
 +- _userLoginName
```

Use your pen as your pointer '_userLoginName' and point it at the first cell. Derefencing the pointer (i.e. using `*ptr` for a pointer `ptr`) means looking at the content of the cell it points at. That is '*_userLoginName' shows into the content of the cell. Writing a pointer of type `char*` or `char const*` does something funny: it follows the pointer and writes the content of each cell it finds until it reaches a cell having the value `\0`.

This should explain the first to outputs. Now, `ptr + 1` looks at the cell next to `ptr`, i.e. `ptr + 1` is another pointer (pull out another pen if necessary) placed the next cell. It does just the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the type of `*_userLoginName`—it is `char`.

Maybe you overlooked that `*` in this context *dereferences* the pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Dereferencing a pointer (such as `*_userLoginName`) always returns the element the pointer is pointing at, in the case of a normal string the first character therein, which is then printed.

Adding `n` to a pointer (such as `_userLoginName+1`) increments the pointer by `n` steps, so if it pointed to the 0th element it will afterwards point to the nth element.

Combine the two to explain the fourth line.

Answer (score 0):

The first `cout` is looking at the pointer `userLoginName` (char* and char[] are very very similar in c++). The `cout` will print all values in memory, treating them as chars, until it comes across a `'\0'` character, which terminates the string.

The second `cout` is looking at one memory element, that pointed to by `userLoginName`, or `userLoginName[0]`.

The third `cout` is doing the same as the first, but the memory address starts 1 char later than userLoginName, as the pointer is of type `char`.

The final cout is the same as the second, but is `userLoginName[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate overloads for `operator<<` at work here: One for char-pointers, and one for chars. The second one, for single characters, simply prints that one character. The first one, for char pointers, treats the pointer as the pointer to the first character in a null-terminated array of characters (a "string") and prints all those.

Combine this with the language syntax that `a[i]` is the same as `*(a + i)` for an array `a`, and you have:

```
cout << s;      // prints all characters, starting at the first
cout << *s;     // prints only the first character, equal to "cout << s[0];"
cout << s + 1;  // prints all  characters, starting at the second
cout << *(s+1); // prints only the second character, equal to "cout << s[1];"
```